# CSS - Glitchy border transition

Tags: html, css

Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/9poh0y28/1/

```
button.products:hover {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #303030;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 4px solid #0085ca;
}
```

For some reason in Chrome there is this weird jump when the border is added. It gets added, and then gets slightly bigger a split second afterwards. Any way to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your `transitions` from `all` to `background-color`:

```
-webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
```

When you use `all`, all of your properties get the transitions. So your border goes from `1px` to `4px`, thus the weird effect.

[Here's your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9poh0y28/2/) changed

Comment: That did it! I was able to add transition: border 0.2s linear; also to get the border to go smoothly.

Comment: Nice! Glad I could help :)